# MATLAB publish, formatting LaTeX output header

Tags: matlab

I have thousands of lines of MATLAB ranging over several scripts that I have commented and broken up into cells. I would now like to publish. I have some universal formatting that I would like to apply. I would also like to be able to publish each script independently. At the moment I have written all these formats into a file called 'Formats.m'. So at the start of every script it publishes with the word 'Format' at the top.

Is there a way I can call in the formatting file without seeing the name published in the final script?

Answer (score 0):

[`publish`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/publish.html) has an option `codeToEvaluate` which might be what you're looking for here.

To publish `foo`, but run `Format` first, try this:

```
>> opts.codeToEvaluate = 'Formats; foo';
>> publish('foo',opts)
```

If you're working from the Editor, the same option is available as a [publish configuration](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/briymz8-1.html).